# make: Circular Makefile.out <- Makefile dependency dropped. C

Tags: gcc, makefile, compilation, cross-compiling

i am trying to write a make file to build and compile for different platforms ( the host machine and an arm board )
when i try to make main.o PLATFORM=HOST it gives me

```
make: Circular sources.mk.out <- sources.mk dependency dropped.
make: Circular Makefile.out <- Makefile dependency dropped.
```

my implemented makefile

```
ifeq ($(PLATFORM) ,MSP432)

# Architectures Specific Flags
LINKER_FILE =msp432p401r.lds
CPU = cortex-m4
ARCH = thumb
SPECS = nosys.specs

# Compiler Flags and Defines
CC =arm-none-eabi-gcc
LD = arm-none-eabi-ld
LDFLAGS = -Wl,-Map=$(TARGET).map -T $(LINKER_FILE)
CFLAGS =-march=armv7e-m -mfloat-abi=hard-mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mcpu=$(CPU) -m$(ARCH) --specs=$(SPECS) -Wall -Werror -g -O0 -std=c99

else

# Architectures Specific Flags
# Compiler Flags and Defines
CC=gcc
LDFLAGS = -Wl,-Map=$(TARGET).map
LD = arm-none-eabi-ld
CFLAGS =  -Wall -Werror -g -O0 -std=c99
endif
OBJS = $(SOURCES:.c=.o)

%.o : %.c
    $(CC) -c $< $(CFLAGS) -D$(PLATFORM)  $(INCLUDES) -o $@

$(TARGET).out: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGs) -o $@
```

can anyone spot the problem with the makefile ?

Comment: The error message is your friend.

Comment: @MustacheMoses i've tried to figure out what it means but i can't find the problem

Comment: Have you tried using a search engine to look up similar errors?

Comment: Have you tried to use the `-d` option _(debug)_ in order to see where the circular dependencies arise?

Comment: By inspection, `TARGET` is undefined, so the default target is `.out`. I don't think this is your real makefile.

Comment: ...And why are you trying to make `main.c`? What do you expect Make to do? Have you succeeded at `HelloWorld`?

Comment: @Beta thanks, i noticed that and it was really the problem.
and i was just testing the makefile (i am a beginner and this is for a course )